# Copy content from files X and Y to create file XY but XY content is all lowercase

Tags: files, dd, cat

What's the right command to copy the content from file `X` and File `Y` to create a new File `XY` with all letters being lowercase?

Comment: Please modify the tags, as you don't actually want to copy or cp anything.

Comment: Do you need to lowercase non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `cat` and `dd`:

```
cat LIST_OF_FILES | dd of=OUTPUT_FILE conv=lcase
```

An example:

```
$ cat file1.txt 
I am File 1.

$ cat file2.txt 
Here is File 2!

$ cat file1.txt file2.txt | dd of=file12.txt conv=lcase
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
29 bytes (29 B) copied, 0,000301417 s, 96,2 kB/s

$ cat file12.txt 
i am file 1.
here is file 2!
```

Comment: Why use `cat` at all? `dd if=LIST_OF_FILES of=OUTPUT_FILE conv=lcase`

Comment: Note that `dd` only works with ASCII letters. `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` would work with any letter, except that the GNU implementation doesn't work with multi-byte characters. GNU `awk`'s `tolower()` function will work or `s/.*/\L&/g` in GNU `sed`.

Comment: @muru, `dd` supports only one `if=file` argument. With `zsh`, you could do `dd < file1 < file2`, but that's `zsh`-specific.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `dd <(cat file1 file2)` should work in bash. Oh, so many ways...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, that should be `dd < <(cat file1 file2)` or `dd if=<(cat file1 file2)` (which btw doesn't work in ksh even though ksh is the one that introduced `<(...)`), but that still invokes `cat`.

Answer (score 10):

Use a combination of `cat` and `tr`:

`cat FILEX FILEY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' > FILEXY`

Comment: Why use `cat` at all? `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < LIST_OF_FILES`

Comment: @muru because of KISS. `cat`'s raison d'etre is to concatenate files.

Comment: @muru In my opinion `< LIST_OF_FILES` won't work with multiple files (only in special shells). Can you give an example what you mean?

Comment: when you believe that there is such a thing as UUOC then all cats are useless..

Comment: @cas Not at all. *Some* uses of cat are useless. In particular, `cat | foo` and `cat file | foo` are useless and should be replaced by `foo` and `< file foo`, respectively. But not all of them are. If you want to concatenate files, use `cat`.

Comment: that was my point.  muru was railing against an appropriate use of cat partly because his belief that UUOC exists blinds him to the fact that cat has its uses.  IMO even if a particular instance of using cat does happen to be useless, there's little point in complaining about it - cat is also useful as a placeholder for any command or pipeline of commands in examples.  And if using cat makes it easier for someone to understand then it's certainly not useless.  The point here is learning, not pedantry.  there are plenty of things worth being pedantic about, the occasional UUOC isn't one of them

Answer (score 1):

`<old_file tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' > new_file`